# API calls with Axios within a Redux Saga's yield call statement prevent the following yield put statement from successfully terminating

Tags: redux, axios, fetch-api, redux-toolkit, redux-saga

I'm making a GET request using Axios inside a saga, and upon completion, I put an action that indicates a successful response.

`my-saga.ts`

```
import { throttle, call, put } from "redux-saga/effects";
import axios from "axios";

import { SuccessfulResponse } from "@/types";

export function* apiWorker() {
  const response: SuccessfulResponse = yield call(
    axios.get,
    "https://my-url.com/api"
  );
  yield put(apiSuccess(response.data.Items));
}

export default function* apiWatcher() {
  yield throttle(1000, "API_REQUEST", apiWorker);
}
```

My actions are set up as normal:

`my-actions.ts`

```
import { createAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import { Items } from "@/types";

export const apiRequest = createAction("API_REQUEST");
export const apiSuccess = createAction(
  "API_SUCCESS",
  (items: Items) => ({
    payload: { items },
  })
);
```

Same with my store:

`my-store.ts`

```
import { createReducer } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import { ItemsContainer } from "@/types";

const initialState: ItemsContainer = {};

const rootReducer = createReducer(initialState as ItemsContainer, (builder) => {
  builder
    .addCase(apiRequest, (_state) => ({}))
    .addCase(apiSuccess, (_state, action) => action.payload);
});

export default rootReducer;
```

With the given saga, I get a successful response when I make an API call (I've `console.logged` the response and it's as expected). It triggers `apiSuccess`, and I can verify that the `apiSuccess` case receives the correct data and runs (I've `console.logged` the `Items` within my `addCase` statement for `apiSuccess`).

But the state never completes updating. Even though I can verify that I'm running that case, and I'm getting the correct payload, no matter how I set the state (whether with a return statement or directly setting the `state.items` property), the state never updates. Moreover, even though the `apiSuccess` reducer case is running, my browser's Redux Devtools extension never shows the `API_SUCCESS` action as being sent, only the `API_REQUEST` action.

To make things even weirder, the entire thing runs just fine, and state updates correctly, when I replace the Axios call with some sample data. It seems to be something to do with `yield calling` Axios.

I've tried replacing Axios with fetch, and creating an intermediary `callApi` function to wrap the promise like so:

```
const callApi = async (url: string) => {
  try {
    return await axios.get(url);
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Nothing seems to work. It would make sense if I was getting an error response from Axios or fetch, but I'm not.

TL;DR I'm at a loss with why simple API calls with Axios within a Redux Saga's `yield call` statement prevent the following `yield put` statement from successfully terminating and state from updating—any ideas what I should try next?

Comment: You are using `redux-toolkit`, why not use `createAsyncThunk`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The issue is that would require rewriting all of my complex asynchronous saga logic (the example I shared above is a very simplified version of what I'm doing). `createAsyncThunk` can be useful for sure, but unfortunately not super realistic for me to refactor all or most of my company's production frontend from sagas to thunks to solve this one issue :(

Comment: In your intermediary example, did you call it like this ? `yield call(apiCall, url)`

Comment: Yes, did that! Unfortunately didn't work :/